# Why does Windows convert the operator "=<" to "= 0<"?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have the following batch file:

```
SET /P FOO=<"foo.txt"
```

This is an attempt to read the contents of `foo.txt` into the variable `FOO`, as suggested in [How to read file contents into a variable in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)
. This method has previously worked fine for me.

When I execute the script, I get the following output:

```
SET /P FOO= 0<"foo.txt"
```

This is not only a display error, the value is not read into the variable. Why does this happen? How do I resolve this?

I'm seeing this on multiple machines, EOL or encoding issues don't seem to be the source.

Comment: Oliver, how is coded the foo.txt, is it an ANSI file or an UTF-8?

Comment: @duDE I've tried both. It doesn't matter

Comment: Either way, the operator is just `<`, and it's functionally equivalent to `0<`.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it doesn't work? I tried to replicate the problem, and here's what I get:

```
D:\>notepad test.bat //i've put SET /P FOO=<"foo.txt" inside it
D:\>echo asdf > foo.txt
D:\>test.bat
D:\>SET /P FOO= 0<"foo.txt"
D:\>echo %FOO%
asdf
D:\>
```

So it adds `0<` but it still applies the data from inside the file to the variable.

Comment: Yes. I am sure it doesn't work. The "not working" part is what drove me to this investigation.

Comment: It does mean that most likely the "not working" part comes from somewhere else entirely (such as the encoding of the _foo.txt_ file).

Comment: You're right, at least for Windows 7. (I'm not able to run this test on Windows 10 at the moment).

Comment: @grawity No. I can reproduce this at will with any file. The original problem was that no variable is set. If I copy the exact command into the CMD, then the variable *is* set. Stop doubting me ;P

Comment: Okay, after several more isolated tests, I have to confirm that this behavior is not the cause of the issue. I still don't understand the behavior though, let alone the source of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the initial question, as @grawity [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1301231/why-does-windows-convert-the-operator-to-0/1301250?noredirect=1#comment1931802_1301231), `=<` is just a short form for `= <0`, which is perfectly fine syntax and actually works as expected (once you test it **correctly**).

So there's nothing wrong with the output and it was just a red herring when I was investigating a different issue.

That issue related to a piece of code, similar to this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET TEST=Fail
ECHO Pass>foo.txt

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
SET /P TEST=<foo.txt
ECHO %TEST%
)
```

When running this, I expected the output to be `Pass`, as that should have been read from the `foo.txt`, but the output is `Fail`. I suspected that this is due to the "mangled" syntax.

However, as @Joey [pointed out](https://superuser.com/questions/1301231/why-does-windows-convert-the-operator-to-0/1301250?noredirect=1#comment1931841_1301250), this behavior is related to [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file).

To make the above code work, it should be rewritten as:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET TEST=Fail
ECHO Pass>foo.txt

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
SET /P TEST=<foo.txt
ECHO !TEST!
)
```

Comment: Read up on delayed expansion (`help set`) and you'll see why your code doesn't work. This has nothing at all to do with the redirection operator. Add another `echo %TEST%` after your `if` statement and you'll get `Pass`.

Comment: @Joey I suspected that it is related to delayed expansion. However, adding the `ECHO` **after** the `IF` kinda negates the point I wanted to make with the script, doesn't it?

Comment: It shows you that `set /p` is working properly; your assumption is the wrong one.

Comment: @Joey Thanks. I've adjusted my answer. I hope I got it right now :P